# iOS UITableView : show only 20 rows from fetchedResultsController that has 500 objects

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm struggling to show only 20 rows from NSFetchedResultsController in UITableView.

Currently UITableView shows all data from NSFetchedResultsController's objects:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to show 20 rows at first, then when user scrolls to 21 row, it'll load 20 more.  But before that, I would like to understand how I can limit tableView rows.

I've searched around, tried suggestions by others, but still lacking understanding.  Please guide me to the light...

Comment: Why not just return `MIN(20,[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]);`?

Comment: Thank you. This worked very nicely.

Comment: hello Dan! I was wondering if you have tried using this solution with nsfetchedresultscontroller controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath: ? It doesn't work for me. Every time the controller changes it returns an error when tries to insert the cells which index is > number I want to display. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSFetchRequest` has a method called `fetchLimit`. You can set it to 20 and it will only fetch 20.

That being said, I'm not quite sure why you want what you described.

Comment: thanks for that but the problem is I need to show the user the total number of results which I'm doing by just counting fetchedObjects.  Obviously setting fetchLimit distort the total results in my case.

Comment: then how about Dan F's comment?

Comment: Yes, I think I can definitely start with Dan and Michaels comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
```

Use:

```
return (20 * X);
```

Where X is the how many times you've added more results to your table view, and of course also limited by the number of records you have in your CoreData database.

The trick here is to decide, in terms of your UI, how to trigger the change to the X increment.  Once you increment X, you can then call UITableView's [`[insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:]` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a).

And of course you need to make sure your backing store matches what's currently displayed in the table (which makes iBlue's answer very relevant also... +1 to them!).

Comment: Hello Michael! I was wondering if you have tried using this solution with nsfetchedresultscontroller controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath: ? It doesn't work for me. Every time the controller changes it returns an error when tries to insert the cells which index is > number I want to display. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The count of the fetchedObjects array might not what you want to do, since it does not update the changes from the persistent store. From NSFetchedResultsController documentation:

> The results array only includes instances of the entity specified by the fetch request (fetchRequest) and that match its predicate. (If the fetch request has no predicate, then the results array includes all instances of the entity specified by the fetch request.)
>
> The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in the controller’s managed object context, not their state in the persistent store. The returned array does not, however, update as managed objects are inserted, modified, or deleted.

If you only want to fetch 20 objects, set the fetch limit of the NSFetchRequest. If you want only to keep 20 objects in memory, use setBatchSize of the NSFetchRequest object.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this example - this implementation includes pull to refresh and also the "load more" effect, which you are trying to achieve :)

https://github.com/shiki/STableViewController